# Cast KERAS Tensor to K.tf.int32

Tags: python, tensorflow, casting, keras, tensor

This is from a Custom Keras Callback
    casted=K.cast((yPred), K.tf.int32)

I absolutely need to cast yPred, which is a Tensor, to the type int32 (The cast is applied to the Tensor content, I know that)

Still, K.cast allow only a conversion to float.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: K.tf? Have you tried simply "int32"?

Comment: Have you tried also K.round?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it works.

Comment: @DanielMöller K.round probably return a float. And if it were to return an int, we still couldn't use it. Keras doesn't allow you to put a Round inside the loss function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
casted = K.cast(yPred,"int32")
```

Comment: As you said, even if I were skeptic, it works. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/cast doesn't agree, which surprise me a lot.... but I gave it a try ad: Tensor("loss_2/dense_42_loss/Cast:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=int32). 
.
.
Thanks!

Comment: The answer is right, but my problems are still not finished. Here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50994041/why-does-this-custom-keras-loss-function-is-giving-an-error-casting . It may be interesting for those who ended up in this question

Answer (score 0):

Casting to an int will work if your backend is Tensorflow.

The `Keras.backend` interface must be the lowest common denominator among all its possible backends. TensorFlow's `cast` supports int. CNTK, another possible backend, does not support `cast` to int.

If you always plan to use TensorFlow as your backend to Keras, casting to int will always work.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/cast

https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.html